# Uploading a zip file to a jsp and extract the content in another jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I want to upload a zip file in a jsp page and the user is sent to another jsp page after he selects and uploads the file.

In this second page I want to

1.)extract the uploaded zip file.

2.)read some content from the extracted file(s) and allow the user to change/edit them

3.)save the user changes in the files.

4.)zip the files again and save it in another destination.

Please suggest me a rough outline of a solution as I am stuck in the phase in which I get the uploaded file and re-direct the user to the second jsp.

Comment: jsp is for view layer, for controller it's better to use servlets/structs actions/spring controllers/etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to upload a zip file in a jsp page...*

Use the following type of form:

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> *...and the user is sent to another jsp page after he selects and uploads the file.*

Hold on. You shouldn't be using JSP for business logic. Raw Java code doesn't belong in a JSP file, but in a real Java class. Let the form submit to a `Servlet`, which in turn processes the file upload and finally forwards the request to a JSP page to display *some* result.

> *1) extract the uploaded zip file.*

Use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to obtain the uploaded file. You can find code examples and tips&tricks(!) in respectively the *User Guide* and *Frequently Asked Questions* sections at their homepage.

You should end up with an `InputStream` containing the uploaded file.

Once having that, then just use [`java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) API to read the uploaded file.

> *2) read some content from the extracted file(s) and allow the user to change/edit them*

Get hold of the data in model objects (javabeans), store them in the request or session scope and use a JSP/EL to display model values in HTML input fields. E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.foo)}">
```

The [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fn:escapeXml`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is just there to prevent [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

> *3) save the user changes in the files.*

Let the form submit to a servlet, gather the new input, write it to some file.

> *4) zip the files again and save it in another destination.*

Use [`ZipOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).

---

**See also**

- [How to upload files with JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831271/how-to-do-this-with-jsp/1832413#1832413)
- [Beginning and Intermediate-Level Servlet/JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/)
- [Lesson: Basic I/O](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/)
- [XSS prevention in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/2658941#2658941)

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the uploaded zip file in a servlet.

For your step 1, extract the zip file contents using http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

Procedure is here http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Example is here http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20447

Step 2 and 3 are simple

Step 4 of creating zip again is available in http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/ (See Zip.java in that page)